# !fileName! (String variable) was unexpected at this time in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, unexpectendoffile

I'm running a batch file that:
1. Go thru ALL *.properties files in C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2
2. Run them
3. compare line by line of the outputted log with ref log
But the cmd.exe keeps throwing me this error: "!fileName! was unexpected at this time. Any ideas?

```
CALL ant clean build compile 
REM Run ENG-zzz.properties  --> output to ENG-zzz.properties.log in Logs dir
REM loop thru/Run ALL .properties file names from "ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2" folder
FOR %%G in (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO (
set flag=true
Set fileName=%%~nxG
set testNum=!fileName:~0,7!
echo Running:!fileName!
java -jar Test.jar !fileName! > Logs\!fileName!.log

ECHO Create: Ref!fileName!.log at C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs
set logPath=C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\!fileName!.log
set refLogPath=C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\Logs\!testNum!-Ref.properties.txt
set lnCorrect=true
set errorLnCount=0
REM if ...Ref.txt doesnt Exist --> check certain lines of the log

REM assume ref.txt exists
<!logPath! (
    For /F "tokens=*" %%R in (!refLogPath!) DO (
        set logLine=
            set /p logLine=
        set refLogLine=%%R

        REM Check line by line of log against refLog
        REM assume ALL times have been replaced with: "xx:xx:xx"

        REM if corresponding lines mismatch
        if NOT !logLine!==!refLogLine! Do (
            set lnCorrect=false
            REM output to command line: can be put into .log/.txt later
            if errorLnCount==1 AND lnCorrect==false DO (
          ECHO The following line(s)  !fileName! are incorrect against corresponding line(s) in !testNum!-Ref.properties.txt 
             )
             ECHO !logLine!
        )
        )
    )

if lnCorrect=true Do Echo !fileName! Passed
  )
Pause
```

Comment: I don't see a `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` anywhere, yet you are obviously attempting to use delayed expansion. Could it be that simple?

Comment: @dbenham: Could be enabled be a CMD command line switch. Not many people might know about it, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit odd (it's simply wrong)
`if lnCorrect=true Do Echo !fileName! Passed`

1. The `IF` statement must not have a `DO` clause.
2. compare needs two equal signs.
3. There are not logic operators like `AND`, `OR`
4. The variables must be expanded to be able to compare them

So your line should look like
`if "!lnCorrect!"=="true" Echo !fileName! Passed`

And the other bug is in the line

```
if errorLnCount==1 AND lnCorrect==false DO (
```

This could be refactored to

```
if !errorLnCount!==1 if !lnCorrect!==false (
```

There is also a problem with the line

```
ECHO The following line(s)  !fileName! are incorrect against
```

The closing parenthesis will cause your problem, as it closes the if-clause and loop.
Remove them or escape them

```
ECHO The following line(s^)  !fileName! are ... corresponding line(s^) in ...
```

Comment: Hey, its still giving me the same error: !fileName! was unexpected at this time?

Comment: It keeps saying that certain characters after echo in:              if errorLnCount==1 AND lnCorrect==false (                           echo The following lines in !fileName! are incorrect against corresponding line(s) in !testNum!-Ref.properties.txt 
     )

Comment: You should add your _partial_ corrected version to your question

Comment: never mind @jeb, its because of the parenthese in (S) thanks for all your help